# How to join a Data and a Localization table in SQL Server, with every data-id having exactly one row of localization table data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, localization, distinct

I have a table with numerical data, that needs to be matched to description data in a variety of different languages. This is achieved by having a 'localizations' table that has an id column that is a FK referencing the table with the data.

What I need is to be able to *join* the data table to the localization table on the ID column, with only one "localization" row matched for each id column– the best matched one based on the language and localization provided.

For example:
given language 'en' and localization 'IN' (doesn't exist in db), I would want to get back the english/GB data joined with the data table.

The localization table looks as follows:

| id | language | localization | default_for_lang | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'en' | 'US' | true | ... |
| 1 | 'en' | 'GB' | false | ... |
| 1 | 'es' | 'MX' | false | ... |
| 1 | 'es' | 'SP' | true | ... |
| 2 | 'en' | 'US' | true | ... |
| 2 | 'en' | 'GB' | false | ... |
| 2 | 'es' | 'MX' | false | ... |
| 2 | 'es' | 'SP' | true | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The tables may be reproduced:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_table (
    id               INT       IDENTITY(1,1)
);

CREATE TABLE localization_table (
    id               INT           foreign key references data_table(id),
    language         VARCHAR(2)    not null,
    localization     VARCHAR(2)    not null,
    default_for_lang BIT           not null default 0,
    name             VARCHAR(255)  not null,
    description      VARCHAR(255)  not null
);
```

I have a *"working"* model, but it isn't performant for larger tables and complex joining of dozens of tables, each with a localization table. So I am asking if there is a more effective way to accomplish this:

```sql
DECLARE @language VARCHAR(2) = 'en'
DECLARE @localization VARCHAR(5) = 'GB'

SELECT dt.*, l.name, l.notes
FROM data_table dt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
    FROM localization_table l
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY l.id
            ORDER BY 
            (
                (case when l.language = @language then 8 else 0 end)+
                (case when l.language = 'en' then 4 else 0 end)+
                (case when l.localization = @localization then 2 else 0 end)+
                (case when l.default_for_lang = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
            ) 
            DESC
    )   
) l 
ON dt.id = l.id
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the example, do you mean requesting en-IN should result in rows where `language='en'` and default_for_lang is true (i.e. en-US)? If not, what's the criteria that would result in en-GB?

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). See the help center for more on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics.

Comment: (Note: the sample data is not in 3NF, and likely not 2NF, depending on the other data columns, which makes it vulnerable to anomalies. In particular, a given language+localization might be the default for one translation, but not another.)

Comment: @outis: Yes, that is exactly correct about the intended outcome for 'en-IN'
I'll also take a look at the linked resources, about formatting & included information, thanks!

Comment: My first request for clarification should still be addressed. What are the rules for localization precedence (described in English)? The sample query embodies some rules explicitly, but these may not match the requirements, and (in any case) an English explanation is still needed. Also, the sample data should be converted to SQL, rather than the ad-hoc format.

Comment: Possibly covered by: "[How to run only the first conditional OR in WHERE?](//stackoverflow.com/q/70846141/90527)". In particular, note [Thorsten Kettner](//stackoverflow.com/a/70846627/90527)'s (accepted) answer that uses an aliased result set from a `WITH` clause for priority values, which may both simplify queries and be more performant. The primary key for the priority result set would need to be changed to `language` and `localization` columns. A temporary table to hold the priorities might also work well.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much of an answer as it is a potential workaround that works for my use case. I'm posting in case it helps anyone with a similar problem.

```sql
SELECT 
     dt.*, l.name, l.notes, l.language, l.localization
FROM data_table dt
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT id,
          STRING_AGG(language, '%%%') AS language, 
          STRING_AGG(ISNULL([localization], '??'), '%%%') AS localization, 
          STRING_AGG(name, '%%%') AS name, 
          STRING_AGG(ISNULL([notes], ' '), '%%%') AS notes
     FROM x_localizations_table
     WHERE 
          (language = @language OR language = 'en') AND 
          (localization = @localization OR is_default_lang_localization = 1)
     GROUP BY id
) l
ON t.id = l.id;
```

This would have the result of returning (for 'es-SP'):

| id | [data] | language | localization | name | notes | [other_lang_data] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | 'en%%%es' | 'US%%%SP' | '[english name]%%%[spanish name]' | '[english notes]%%%[spanish notes]' | ... |

Thus, in whatever server is being used (in my case, Express in Node.js) you can split the strings of the lang columns by the deliminator string passed into the SQL statement, and select the best fit from the resulting list. It would, in theory, provide four options maximum:

1. The fallback language with the default localization for that language (in my example, english is the fallback with 'US' as the default localization for english)
2. The fallback language with the matching localization given
3. The correct language with the wrong localization, using the default localization for the language.
4. The correct language with the correct localization, if the localization is different from the default.

For example, if we had 'es-GB' as a valid language combination in the question's example database we would get:

1. en-US (because it matches the fallback language of English, and 'US' is the default localization for English)
2. en-GB (because it matches the fallback language of English, and matches the provided localization of 'GB')
3. es-SP (because it matches the correct language of Spanish, and 'SP' is the default localization for Spanish)
4. es-GB (because it matches the correct language of Spanish, and matches the provided localization of 'GB')

all rolled into the text fields to be parsed.

To be fair, ***I am well aware that this isn't a true solution to the question asked*** and I'll not be accepting this answer for that reason. However, if a better answer does not arise, hopefully this workaround is helpful to anyone with a similar situation.